# How to create an object by adding a variable to a fixed value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to write a program to open a large amount of files and run them through a function I made called "sort". Every one of my file names starts with "sa1", however after that the characters vary based on the file. I was hoping to do something along the lines of this:

```R
 for(x in c("Put","Characters","which","Vary","by","File","here")){
     sa1+x <- read.csv("filepath/sa1+x",header= FALSE)
     sa1+x=sort(sa1+x)
     return(sa1+x)
}
```

In this case, say that x was 88. It would open the file sa188, name that dataframe sa188, and then run it through the function sort. I dont think that writing sa1+x is the correct way to bind together two values, but I dont know a way to.

Comment: Even better, use `list.files(pattern="^sa1")` to collect a vector of the filenames, then loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a list to contain the data in each csv file, and loop over the filenames using `paste0`.

```
file_suffixes <- c("put","characters","which","vary","by","file","here")
numfiles <- length(file_suffixes)

list_data <- list()
sorted_data <- list()
filename <- "filepath/sa1"

for (x in 1:numfiles) {
  list_data[[x]] <- read.csv(paste0(filename, file_suffixes[x]), header=FALSE)
  sorted_data[[x]] <- sort(list_data[[x]])
}
```

I am not sure why you use `return` in that loop. If you're writing a function, you should be returning the `sorted_data` list which contains all your post-sorting data.

Note: you shouldn't call your function `sort` because there is already a base R function called `sort`.

Additional note: you can use `dir()` and regex parsing to find all the files which start with "sa1" and loop over all of them, thus freeing you from having to specify the `file_suffixes`.